# Are multiple jobs on the same environment possible in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm setting up my self-hosted gitlab CI pipeline, and the following simple CI script fails on `release bar` step with the following error message:

> The deployment job is older than the previously succeeded deployment job, and therefore cannot be run

It seems that gitlab does not allow multiple jobs to run on the same environment. Is there any way I can achieve this? I could merge all *release* jobs into a single one, but this seems a bit limiting, making all my steps run serially instead of in parallel. Is there any reason this is not possible?

Below is a gitlab-ci exemplifying the problem:

```yaml
stages:
  - release

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
      variables:
        STAGE: dev
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        STAGE: prod

release foo:
  stage: release
  tags: [shell]
  environment: $STAGE
  script:
    - echo $STAGE
    - echo "Releasing foo..."

release bar:
  stage: release
  tags: [shell]
  environment: $STAGE
  script:
    - echo $STAGE
    - echo "Releasing bar..."
```

I also thought of renaming the environment per job, but this also doesn't work because I have some specific environment variables that are only visible on Gitlab's environments `dev` and `prod`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here. It doesnt make sense to have two deployments tracked as the same environment. You might want to group environments https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#group-similar-environments like `$STAGE/foo` and `$STAGE/bar`

Comment: If I change the environment name to `$STAGE/foo`, will the execution be able to fetch the variables defined for the environment `$STAGE`? For example, I have AWS variables for `dev` and `prod`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a few options:

### Disable the deployment safety feature

You can disable the [prevent outdated deployment jobs setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/deployment_safety.html#prevent-outdated-deployment-jobs) which will allow your jobs to run in the scenario without any other configuration changes. Just be aware that you can potentially run into the issue this setting is meant to prevent (as described in the linked documentation).

### Use different environments

You can set each job to deploy to a differently named environment, like `$STAGE/foo` or `$STAGE/bar`.

> I have some specific environment variables that are only visible on Gitlab's environments dev and prod.

To get around this issue, you can change the [protected environment variable rule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#limit-the-environment-scope-of-a-cicd-variable) to a wildcard, like `prod/*` or `dev/*`.

[image: wildcard rule]

Comment: Oh, the second solution seems ideal! But I don't see a way to put a wildcard in the environment scope. I only get a drop down listing All, dev, prod. Is there another way to edit the environment scope of a variable?

Comment: @IanLiuRodrigues it may not be clear from the UX, but you can type into the field -- if you type a value not matching an existing environment, you will get an option to  'create wildcard' scope. I've edited the question to add a screenshot of what I mean.